# How to handle a big CSV file?

Tags: mysql, database, file, list, csv

I am planning to add the list of all cities in the world to my application (*BTW*: I am using Ruby, Ruby on Rails and MySQL) so I thought to use the CSV file downloaded from the [www.maxmind.com](http://www.maxmind.com/app/worldcities) website.

However, I am worried and doubtful because the unpacked file is about *151,1 MB* on disk (!) and I should put all those values in my database. *How do you advice to proceed (also for MySQL indexes...)?*

Comment: This is a bit of a nonsensical question... Whether the db can handle that size depends on where you're hosting it. What indexing to use depends upon your use case. My advice is to proceed by a) playing around and b) asking a definite question.

Comment: @amaidment - Before now I never had problems like this. Perhaps the question may appear to you a little "nonsensical" but this comes from my inexperience in the field.

Comment: So... what is it that you want to know? What is the problem?

Comment: @amaidment - I would like to know, for example for performance reasons, if it is a "right way" to load all that CSV data in the database, how much time it can take to load that data, if is it adviced to load all that data... and some tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using LOAD INFILE is the only way to import it, but index and performance considerations will be dependant on what you import and how you're going to use it.  Research, research, research...good starting poing is [Large Files with LOAD DATA INFILE](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/07/03/how-to-load-large-files-safely-into-innodb-with-load-data-infile/)